# Pushing a list into a list in redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I have few lists and i want to push those lists in another list using redis. Is this probable?

```
eg: list_1 => [value_1, value_2,value_3,value_4]
    list_2 => [value_1, value_2,value_3,value_4]
    list_3 => [value_1, value_2,value_3,value_4]
```

Now i want to push these lists in a master list

```
eg: master_list => [list_1 => [value_1, value_2,value_3,value_4],list_2 => [value_1, value_2,value_3,value_4],list_3 => [value_1, value_2,value_3,value_4]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis does not support nested structures with depth > 1, lists of lists and alike structures are not contemplated.

You have to do it within your application (eg. serialize/deserialize your data; store references to redis lists...)